# How to put variable from constructor to method?

Tags: java

I have code like this:

```
public class Class1 {

    public void method1() {
        ...
        Class2 c = new Class2(i);
        ...
    }

    public Class1(int i) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I get variable i from constructor to method1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a field in the class. E.g.

`private int i;`

Then in the constructor set `this.i = i;` You can then access `i` from anywhere in the class.

To be honest this is pretty basic stuff so Id suggest reading up on Java basics before continuing a project :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put `i` as an instance variable.

```
public class Class1 {

    private int i;

    public void method1 () {
       ...
       Class2 c = new Class2(i);
       ...
    }
    public Class1 (int num){
        this.i = num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use member variable i to store the value

```
public class Class1 { 
  private int i;

  public void method1 () { ... 

   Class2 c = new Class2(i); 
    ... } 

   public Class1 (int i){ 
       this.i = i;
... 
}}
```